# Let-bind a variable while font-locking

Tags: font-lock, optimization

I am writing a font-lock rule that calls a function to decide what
face to apply to a symbol. Here's a simplified version:

```
("\\(?1:\\s_+\\)"
 (1 (the-function 1)))
```

The problem is that this function needs to generate some data that is
just a little bit slow to compute. So, when jit-font-lock starts
calling this function for every symbol in the visible buffer, the lag
is noticeable.

I could `setq` this “slightly-expensive” data to a variable,

```
(setq data-cache (generate-data))
```

and then `the-function` could just use `data-cache` instead of calling
`generate-data` every time. But then I would have to jump through some
non-trivial hoops to make sure that this cache is always properly
invalidated.

**Q:** Does the font-lock engine offer help in this regard? How can I make
sure it only runs `(generate-data)` once per redisplay?

Ideally, I would like to specify something like *“let-bind `data-cache` to
the return value of `(generate-data)`”*. This way I would know that
this cache was never outdated.

Comment: When should the cache be invalidated? (Or IOW, what does the return value of `(generate-data)` depend on?)

Comment: @Francesco The cache does **not** need to be invalidated while font-lock is doing its thing (which is why I was hoping font-lock could let-bind it for me). Technically, it needs to be invalidated before each user command, though I can think of other ways it could be done. The return value of `generate-data` depends on output from an asynchronous background process, and it affects the way that we handle user commands.

Comment: You could perhaps use font-lock's indirection mechanism, setting `font-lock-fontify-region-function` to a function which let-binds `data-cache` around the call to the prior value of `font-lock-fontify-region-function`. Sort of like an around-advice, except the indirection mechanism allows you to do it in a cleaner way.

Comment: @Francesco That's interesting. I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Francesco Yep, it works. Would you like to make that an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perhaps use font-lock's indirection mechanism, setting `font-lock-fontify-region-function` to a function which let-binds `data-cache` around the call to the prior value of `font-lock-fontify-region-function`. Sort of like an around-advice, except the indirection mechanism allows you to do it in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Elisp has closures now. Something like this should work:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-    
(let ((list (let (cache)
              (list (lambda ()
                      (unless cache
                        (message "setting cache")
                        (setq cache 42))
                      cache)
                    (lambda ()
                      (message "invalidating cache")
                      (setq cache nil))))))
  (fset 'do-stuff (car list))
  (fset 'invalidate-cache (cadr list)))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'invalidate-cache)
```